# Physics simulation and image plane

Tags: image, fluid-simulation

I am trying to make some 3d video effect. Is it possible to apply physics simulation on an image/video plane such that it interact with other objects in the scene? E.g. can a video becomes fluid and interact with a obstacle to create splashes?

Comment: The plane itself can be used as part of simulations just like any other object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using the fSPY add-on. You can take a reference image, and then use the fSPY guides to model a scene based off of the objects in the picture. You can then import the .fspy file into Blender, and create a fluid simulation with it. This is the best way to do it.